# Animation in MATLAB for Robotics

Tags: matlab, robotics

Here is my code so far:

```
function P = RobotPosition(T)
    x = T(1,4);
    y = T(2,4);
    z = T(3,4);
    
    P = [x y z];
   

    
function T = RobotConv(theta,d,a,alpha)
    rad = pi/180;
    M_theta = [cos(theta*rad) -sin(theta*rad) 0 0;sin(theta*rad) cos(theta*rad) 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    
    M_d = [1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 d;0 0 0 1];
    M_a = [1 0 0 a;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    M_alpha = [1 0 0 0;0 cos(alpha*rad) -sin(alpha*rad) 0;0 sin(alpha*rad) cos(alpha*rad) 0; 0 0 0 1];
    
    T=M_theta*M_d*M_a*M_alpha;
```

```
% command
clc
clear

framemax = 100;
M=moviein(framemax);
set(gcf,'Position',[100 100 640 480]);


%theta1 = 0:30/100:30;
%theta2 = 0:45/100:45;

theta1 = 0:360/100:360;
theta2 = 0:360/100:360;


for k = 1:100+1 % +1 to utilise all angles in theta including the last one
T1=RobotConv(theta1(k), 0, 3, 0);
T2=RobotConv(theta2(k), 0, 2, 0);

p0 = [0 0 0];
p1 = RobotPosition(T1);
p2 = RobotPosition(T1*T2);
figure(1)
X = [p0(1) p1(1) p2(1)];
Y = [p0(2) p1(2) p2(2)];
plot(X,Y,'o-')
axis([-1 8 -1 8]);
grid
M(k) = getframe(gcf);


%%
%{
%saving the a gif of the robot
frame = getframe(gca);
im = frame2im(frame);
[imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
if k == 1
imwrite(imind,cm,'robot.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
else
imwrite(imind,cm,'robot.gif','gif','WriteMode','append');
end
%}
%%

end
```

The problem is that we need to

1. Divide the 30° and 45° into 100 steps. That is
   theta1 = 0:30/100:30;
   theta2 = 0:45/100:45;
2. Key in the following code as an m-file

```
framemax = 100;
M=moviein(framemax);
set(gcf,'Position',[100 100 640 480]);
for k = 1:100
 T1=RobotConv(theta1(k), 0, 3, 0);
 T2=RobotConv(theta2(k), 0, 2, 0);

 p0 = [0 0 0];
 p1 = RobotPosition(T1);
 p2 = RobotPosition(T1*T2);
 figure(1)
 X = [p0(1) p1(1) p2(1)];
 Y = [p0(2) p1(2) p2(2)];
 plot(X,Y,'o-')
 axis([-1 8 -1 8]);
 grid
 M(k) = getframe(gcf);
end
```

3. Observe the animation of the 2-link robot. Change both angles of θ1 and θ2 to be 360°.
   Modify the code to observe the **whole movement.**

The attached files are as follows:

```
function P = RobotPosition(T)
    x = T(1,4);
    y = T(2,4);
    z = T(3,4);
    P = [x y z];
end
```

And

```
function T = RobotConv(theta,d,a,alpha)
    rad = pi/180;
    
    M_theta = [cos(theta*rad) -sin(theta*rad) 0 0;sin(theta*rad) cos(theta*rad) 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    M_d = [1 0 0 0;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 d;0 0 0 1];
    M_a = [1 0 0 a;0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1];
    M_alpha = [1 0 0 0;0 cos(alpha*rad) -sin(alpha*rad) 0;0 sin(alpha*rad) cos(alpha*rad) 0; 0 0 0 1];
    T=M_theta*M_d*M_a*M_alpha;
end
```

My code is not compiling correctly and I am not sure why.

Comment: Matlab code isn't compiled. Where is the error?

Comment: Please condense your code down to a [mre]. 
It's a pain to read lines after lines of irrelevant code. 
The exercise of creating a MRE forces you to look at your code and try to isolate the problem, which can often help you figure out the issue without even having to ask on SO.

Comment: Please do not be rude. I do not understand what you mean. All you have to do is copy and paste.

Comment: _"All you have to do is copy and paste"_: Please read [ask]. The more details you give, the easier it is for others to help you. When you ask for help with an error, it's reasonable to expect you to tell us what the error is. What did you not understand? [That Matlab isn't a compiled language?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/358105-is-matlab-a-compiler) And what part of my comment did you think is rude? Asking for more details is not rude. Neither is asking what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `end` statement at the end of each of your function blocks - fairly sure that's why it won't run, assuming that first block of code is a single file.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response; I will try this now